# Are POSIX Threads User Level?

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads, posix

It is my understanding that POSIX threads ( things like pthread_create) are user level threads not kernel level threads. That is, they do not create a separate process in the kennel. That is, if my C program spawns 10 threads and I run the PS command, I would not expect to see each thread as a separate process. Am I correct about that?

I am running under Window 10 using Cygwin. Would the answer be different if I was using Linux? Therefore, I conclude that POSIX threads are user level. Is that correct?

Bob

Answer (score 0):

POSIX does not specify how threads must be implemented, just how they must act from the programmer's point of view.

In most actual implementations, including Cygwin and glibc on Linux, POSIX threads are in fact backed by individual kernel-level threads.

Whether those threads show up under the `ps` command is a separate question.  Often, it does not show individual kernel-level threads within the same process unless additional command-line options are used (eg the procps-ng version of `ps` has the `-L` command line option).